# Inline Bokeh Graph with Zeppelin

Tags: bokeh, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to display Bokeh charts inline in Zeppelin using the Pyspark interpreter?

In Jupiter for instance this could be done using the command `output_notebook()` to load bokeh js.

Here is an example to produce a simple line chart.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

# create a new plot 
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title="Simple Line Plot")

# add a line renderer
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2)

show(p) # show the results
```

Comment: As far as I know, no one has reached out to us about Zeppelin support. There have never been any GH issues or requests about it, and none of the core dev team has ever mentioned it. (For example, I'm not actually familiar with Zeppelin at all, I had never heard of it before seeing this). This is fairly specialized, so it's probably something that an interested community member will have to contribute or figure out, but if you do find a solution I'd appreciate it if you would share it with us (on GH or the mailing list) so we can include it in our documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually registered to post this - I'm attempting to get this to work, but running into some interesting issues.

It appears that the Bokeh notebook output depends on IPython notebook, which zeppelin may not.

For the static output, a lot of the resources that are common to IPython notebook are not readily available in Zeppelin.

I'm attempting a workaround here that may end up functional though - Zeppelin has some Angular mark-up that might be used for rendering the Bokeh HTML files.

I just got it inline with the following:

```
s = "%html "
txt = open('log_lines.html').read()
s += txt
print(s)
```

**Edit:** It looks like you still have to call show() on your graph/object to create the file to show. This doesn't appear to create an error, but I'm fairly new to Bokeh still.

Comment: I was intending to add this as a comment but do not have the reputation to - I'll hopefully have some code in a few hours against this.

Comment: A easy and dirty work around is to put your Bokeh html in a web server folder (I used Apache) and read it back into Zeppelin using localhost

Comment: That is awesome - I just got it inline with the following:


s = "%html "
txt = open('log_lines.html').read()
s += txt
print(s)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bokeh >= 0.12.7 you can use Jeff Zhang's [`bkzep`](https://github.com/zjffdu/bkzep) package. E.g., do this outside Zeppelin:

```
pip install bkzep
```

Then, as it says at https://github.com/zjffdu/bkzep#how-to-use, you just do this in a Zeppelin notebook bound to the Spark interpreter group:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
import bkzep
output_notebook(notebook_type='zeppelin')
```

Then you should be able to see Bokeh plots inline in your notebook. I can confirm this works in Zeppelin 0.7.0 using Bokeh 0.12.13. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed chord plot for my project and succesfully adapted bokeh sample to run both in pyspark and in python interpreters in Zeppelin. Support for Zeppelin still needs some love, but works well enough for my purposes.

```
%pyspark

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Chord
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.sampledata.les_mis import data

nodes = data['nodes']
links = data['links']

nodes_df = pd.DataFrame(nodes)
links_df = pd.DataFrame(links)

source_data = links_df.merge(nodes_df, how='left', left_on='source', right_index=True)
source_data = source_data.merge(nodes_df, how='left', left_on='target', right_index=True)
source_data = source_data[source_data["value"] > 5]  # Select those with 5 or more connections

chord_from_df = Chord(source_data, source="name_x", target="name_y", value="value")
#output_file('chord_from_df.html')
output_notebook(notebook_type='zeppelin')
show(chord_from_df)
```